# Angular sharing data to Components using service fails

Tags: service, dependency-injection, angular6, angular-components

I'm having 2 services in my angular frontend, one for API calls and one for sharing data two different components. So the second service is using the API service.

If I only use the API service and subscribe my Observables inside my component, everything works fine(view in xxx.component.html).

So if I declare the two services as providers inside app.module and inject the API Service inside the sharing service, it won't work any more.

Using debugger, I always get variable "tmp" not defined in settings.service.ts

I know, I could do this also with also with @Input for child components, but i think using a service is a much nicer way also for decoupling components.

Any suggestions :)?

Below my Code:

api.service.ts

```
export class ApiService {
    API_URL = 'https://localhost:44381/api/v1';
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    /** GET settings from API*/
    getSettings(): Observable<Setting[]> {
        return this.httpClient.get<Setting[]>(this.API_URL + '/settings')
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError('getSettings', [])));
    }
}
```

settings.service.ts

```
export class SettingsService {

   tmp: Setting[];

   constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

   getSettings(): void {
       this.apiService.getSettings()
         .subscribe(settings =>
           this.tmp = settings);
   }

   getData(): Setting[] {
       this.getSettings();
       return this.tmp;
   }
}
```

settings.component.ts

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
    settings: Setting[];

    constructor(private settingService: SettingsService) { }

    // Load Setting while starting
    ngOnInit() {
        // this.getSettings();
        this.settings = this.settingService.getData();
    }

    // old code when using only API service which works..
    /*getSettings(): void {
        this.apiService.getSettings()
          .subscribe(settings => this.settings = settings);
    }*/
}
```

settings.component.hmtl

```
<div>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>keyname</th>
      <th>value</th>
      <th>defaultValue</th>
      <th align="right">text</th>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let s of settings">
      <td>{{s.keyName}}</td>
      <td>{{s.wert}}</td>
      <td>{{s.defaultValue}}</td>
      <td align="right">{{s.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem resides into async functionality. The `subscribe` method is used to  wait for an async operation. That means that when you execute a particular request, for example a remote request, you don't want to stop the entire flow execution waiting for the response. But rather you want to make the request and execute all other code in the meanwhile that the server is processing your request and is sending it's response.

So let's analyze what is the flow of this code execution

```
getSettings(): void {
       this.apiService.getSettings()
         .subscribe(settings =>
           this.tmp = settings);
   }

getData(): Setting[] {
       this.getSettings();
       return this.tmp;
   }
```

1. `this.getSettings()` executes a request and subscribe for it's
   response
2. then while it's still waiting for subscribed response you return immediately `this.tmp`, that is still undefined
3. after a time your subscribed request ends, you obtain your response and assign that value to your `this.tmp` variable

If you have splitted your logic into 2 services to manage syncronism problems, consider to use Subject

**Possible solution with Subject**

Service

```
export class SettingsService {

   API_URL = 'https://localhost:44381/api/v1';

   settingsSource = new Subject<Setting>();
   settings$ = this.settingsSource.asObservable();

   constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

   getSettings(): void {
       this.apiService.getSettings().subscribe(settings =>
           this.settingsSource.next(settings);
       );
   }

   getData(): Setting[] {
       this.getSettings();
       return this.tmp;
   }

   get result$(): Observable<Setting> {
      return this.settings$;
   }
}
```

Component

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

    subscription: Subscription;
    settings: Setting[];

    constructor(private settingService: SettingsService) { }

    // Load Setting while starting
    ngOnInit() {

        // subscribe for settings
        this.resSubscription = this.searchService.result$.subscribe(result => {
            this.resList = result.result;
        });

        // request settings
        this.settings = this.settingService.getData();
    }
}
```

As you can see `SettingsComponent` subscribe to `settings$` `Observable` (the `$` is a convention for `Observable`), then it ask for data to the service.
When the service receives response data push them into `settingsSource`, it's `Observable` version (`settings$`) receives data and all subscribed components get advised

Comment: So e.g. so using subject in services and maybe return them as observables to the components could be a better implementation?
Is it bad practise to join my two services into one service?

Comment: it isn't a bad practice if you need it for some reason. in your case i can't find a real reason, but you could. i'll post an example